# Add and remove css class only during scroll in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, event-handling, css-animations

I am working on a mockup blog for my portfoilio which has a grid of posts which are **400x400** cards with a hover effect that increases scale and adds a drop shadow (this is rendered in the dashboard route).

I have noticed however that when scrolling my page, the pointer will get hung up on the cards and stop registering scroll when the animation is enabled. I have come across this article (https://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/pointer-events-60fps) discussing the performance benefits of disabling pointer events to the body on scroll however I cannot figure out how to do this in react.

How would you add a class to the document body in React ONLY while scrolling and remove that class as soon as the scroll event had ended? Maybe with a `setTimeOut` in some way?? I feel like that would be a janky solution...

I included the code I am looking to implement this in, I don't know if that will help. The scroll event I have set up already is to maintain the scroll position of the page while the navbar is extended.

```
export default class Layout extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hasMenuOpen: false,
      scroll: {x: 0, y: 0},
    };
    this.handleScrollY = _.debounce(this.handleScrollY, 250);
    this.handleWidthChange = _.debounce(this.handleWidthChange, 250);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScrollY);
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleWidthChange);
    console.log('mount');
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    if (prevState.hasMenuOpen) {
      /* eslint-disable */
      let {x, y} = prevState.scroll;
      /* eslint-enable */
      // correct scroll y position back to 0 for positions <= 100
      window.scrollTo(x, (y <= 100 ? y = 0 : y));
    }
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScrollY);
    window.removEventListener('resize', this.handleWidthChange);
  }
  // if menu is open an y = 0 (i.e position: fixed was added),
  // scroll = previous states scroll
  // else if you scroll and the menu isn't open, scroll = windows new scroll pos
  handleScrollY = () => {
    const y = window.scrollY;
    const x = window.scrollX;
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      if (this.state.hasMenuOpen && y === 0) {
        return {scroll: Object.assign({}, prevState.scroll)};
      }
      return {scroll: Object.assign({}, prevState.scroll, {x}, {y})};
    });
  }
  handleWidthChange = () => {
    console.log(window.innerWidth);
    if (this.state.hasMenuOpen) {
      return this.handleBurgerClick();
    }
    return null;
  }
  handleBurgerClick = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      hasMenuOpen: !prevState.hasMenuOpen
    }));
  }
  handleLinkClick = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      hasMenuOpen: false
    }));
  }
  render() {
    const scrollTop = {
      top: `-${this.state.scroll.y}px`,
    };
    console.log(this.state.scroll);
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Navbar onClick={this.handleBurgerClick} hasMenuOpen={this.state.hasMenuOpen} onLinkClick={this.handleLinkClick} />
        <div className={this.state.hasMenuOpen ? styles.scroll_lock : ''} style={this.state.hasMenuOpen ? scrollTop : {}}>
          <main className={styles.page_margin} >
            <div className={this.state.hasMenuOpen ? styles.margin_extended : styles.margin_top}>
              <Route path='/' exact component={Dashboard} />
              <Route path='/new-post' component={NewPost} />
            </div>
          </main>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

For example I have tried setting `document.body.style.pointerEvents = 'auto'` in `componentDidMount()` and disabling it in the `handleScrollY()` however this obviously doesn't work as pointer events are never restored once the scroll event occurs. I have also tried setting it in `componentDidUpdate()` but that doesn't seem to work either as no component is being updated when the scroll event isn't happening.

Comment: TL;DR You need to toggle a `className` if the user is scrolling? If so why not a simpler approach of adding an event listener to the scroll and toggling the state?

Comment: I need to add it on the body however I only need to add the class while the window is scrolling and remove it as soon as the scroll stops. How would i toggle the state back after the scroll has stopped, the event only fires while the scroll is happening?

Comment: Check if you can adjust my answer for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

One way of toggling a css class is:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  document.removeEventListener('scroll');
}
componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
    const that = this;
    if (!that.state.isScrolling) {
      that.setState({ isScrolling: true });
      setTimeout(() => {
        that.setState({ isScrolling: false });
      }, 300);
    }
  });
}
```

And then use the `state` or `props` to toggle the `className`

in your JSX something like

```
return (
  <div className={`class1 class2 class99 ${this.state.isScrolling ? 'scrolling' : 'not-scrolling'}`} >Content</div>
)
```

Comment: wouldn't this be bad to add in render because it will be constantly adding event listeners to the dom after each re-render?

Comment: You are right! You taught me something new. Edited it and after checking it with Chrome devTools I can see only one event listener at a time.